# Android Corona sdk textInput event listener for new text

Tags: android, sdk, listener, coronasdk, textinput

I have tried without success to create an event listener that detects any new text entered into a textInput. I want the listener to call another function whenever the text is changed by just one character. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: use runtime listener to check the string
(string.gmatch and string.len) refer:http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/string/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice. the Runtime listener would probably work, but I finally got the textField listener to work by ignoring the events. I wanted another function to be called when any event happens. I don't like doing it that way, but I'll see how it works over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
local function fctTextFieldListener(oEvent)
    if "began" == oEvent.phase then
        -- First edition
    elseif "editing" == oEvent.phase then
        -- During edition
    elseif "submitted" == oEvent.phase then
        -- End of edition
    end
end

local oTextField = native.newTextField( nX, nY, nWidth, nHeight)
oTextField:addEventListener( 'userInput', fctTextFieldListener )
```

You can access the oTextField text using oTextField.text :)
In your case you would need to call your function either in the 'began' event if it's only on first edition, or 'editing' event on further editions.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the example. I finally resorted to not looking for any events inside the listener, and it worked. When I tried before, I checked for the "began" phase just to make sure the listener was doing something.